# How to update navigation properties / related tables in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-update, scalar-context

I have an object `Customer` with a navigation property `Days` (days is a separate table which have - day_id, customer_id - FK).

```
mycontext.Customers.ApplyCurrentValues(cust);
mycontext.SaveChanges();
```

This only updated the scalar properties of Customer, not days. Is There any smart way to update Days? (without iterating manually on days..)? if not - is there any best practice to update the second table (days)?
If it's possible please write the explicit code should be used.

p.s. I'm currently using EF 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do it without iterating manually on related entities. Have a look at this question and answer which might be helpful.[MVC Entity Framework modifying child entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081683/mvc-entity-framework-modifying-child-entities/12085011#12085011)

Comment: I got the impression that it suppose to be possible from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606866/cannot-get-relationship-to-update-for-navigation-properties-in-entity-framework), but couldn't implement it, does that post not relevant to the situation I describe?

Comment: @BornToCode: Yes, the post linked in your comment is not relevant because you have a navigation *collection* to update, the other post is about updating a navigation *reference*. An approach to update collections is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5540956/270591 (It's for `DbContext`/EF>=4.1 though, but the idea and the code should be translatable to `ObjectContext`/EF 4.0.)

Comment: Thank you for your patience with my questions, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`GraphDiff`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/) library if you want a simple and easy way to work with disconnected object.

```
mycontext.UpdateGraph(cust, map => map.OwnedCollection(x => x.Days));
mycontext.SaveChanges();
```

This will insert or update customer object and also updating `Days` collection as well.

Comment: just to point out that for this to work you will need to set `myContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to true (if it is disabled).